# Why is my Application_BeginRequest() not invoked when the client request has a self-signed certificate?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, ssl

I have an ASP.NET application that is hosted on a separate server. I wired up `Application_BeginRequest()` in Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //logging here      
}
```

Now I've created a .pfx file with a self-signed certificate and try to use the certificate to request a URL on the server.

The following code runs fine:

```
String url = "https://myserver.com/MyController/Magic";
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
var response = request.GetResponse();
```

and I see logging from `Application_BeginRequest()` in the logs.

But the following code (to the very same URL)

```
String url = "https://myserver.com/MyController/Magic";
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
var certData = File.ReadAllBytes(pathToPfxFile);
var cert = new X509Certificate2(certData, password);
request.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
var response = request.GetResponse();
```

which only loads the certificate and attaches it to the request always yields HTTP 403.16 and I don't see logging from `Application_BeginRequest()` in the logs.

What am I missing? Why wouldn't the request pass to managed code?

Comment: What is the sub-code of your 403, e.g. 403.7 or 403.16 (Client certificate is untrusted or invalid)? Don't you get any other information from the error you receive?

Comment: @OskarLindberg: It's 403.16.

Comment: So, based on the 403.16, I'd say it's likely that the problem is related to how you create and manage the certificates rather than to you code. Did you install the certificate on the web server, like I asked? Maybe you need to read up on how certificate chains and management?

Comment: You choose not to be very informative, so it's hard to know what to say. I mean, how's the web server configured? How's the certificate created? Did you look at the tutorials? The way I see it, your question has been answered to the extent possible. StackOverflow really isn't about getting other people to do your work for you. I suggest you regroup, read on and possibly return with a more explicit question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the IIS is configured to "accept" client certificates, I think it may not necessarily deny access if one is not provided, but try to validate it if one is submitted, and furthermore give you a 403 if that fails.

In this scenario it seems plausible that the 403 is accurate in that something is wrong with the certificate or how you manage it - hard to say. The other possible settings are "require" and "ignore" - maybe try changing and see if that makes any difference.

There are many peripheral circumstances outside of the actual code you write that may affect this process, the details of which was not supplied in your question (possibly because it is kind of hard).  I'm sure you're already aware of this, but it makes it hard to provide a well targeted answer.

Did you install the certificate on the web server? The certificate needs to resolve as part of a chain where it in itself or its issuer is trusted.

When employing the X509Certificate2 class to generate the certificate, a temporary container is created. The private key may be deleted from this container when no longer "referenced". To create a "permanent" key container, use the X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet flag, like so:

```
var certData = new X509Certificate2(pathToPfxFile, password,
                                           X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
```

Here are some links to a couple of tutorials: [Client Certificate Validation in ASP.NET](http://www.piotrwalat.net/client-certificate-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-and-windows-store-apps/); [The HttpWebRequest and Using Client Certificates](http://www.iramellor.com/The-HttpWebRequest-and-Using-Client-Certificates).

The general recommendation is not to store the certificate information in a file, but to use the certificate store.

[EDIT]
Based on the new information that the error you receive in fact is a 403.16, the answer to your question as lined out in the headline is: Because your certificate is invalid or not trusted by the IIS, as soon as your request hits it and is deemed invalid, a 403.16 error is raised and the request rejected. That is, before the Application_BeginRequest event is ever raised, hence before your logging code gets any chance of being executed.

Comment: Okay, what's the proper sequence to get the described setup working then? I've generated the certificate and I attach it to the request. what else should I do?

Comment: Updated my answer with a suggestion and a brief explanation on why that change to your code might make a difference. Let me know it that helps or not.

Comment: I tried `X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet` - the behavior is the same.

Comment: OK. As a reaction to the new knowledge that the error is in fact a 403.16, you should focus on getting the actual certificate management straight. Edited my answer to include this information.

Comment: Thanks Oskar! I was having the same issue, 403.16, and the problem was that the certificate chain was invalid because the root certificate was not in the Trusted Root Certification Authority folder.